# UIImage not writing to or appearing on Desktop

Tags: debugging, uiimage, nsdata

For whatever reason, I'm not having the UIImage appear on my desktop. I'm using this code as a means of debugging. However, I'm pretty sure that I am receiving an image since the UIImage in the debugger is not null.

```
UIImage *imgageProfile = [UIImage imageWithData:
                                   [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                                    [NSURL URLWithString: sUrlPic]]];


            // Use this code to debug images
            NSURL *aLocalURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"file:///Users/snuffles753/Desktop/"];
            NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imgageProfile);
            [imageData writeToURL:aLocalURL atomically:YES];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-[NSData writeToURL:…]` takes a URL that includes the name of the file you'd like created. It will `**not** take the URL of a folder, and automatically create a file inside of that. So your current code is attempting to overwrite an existing directory, which then fails.

Instead, specify the filename explicitly:

```
NSURL *aLocalURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"file:///Users/snuffles753/Desktop/debug.png"];
```